# Xpath String return null in UIPath with VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, rpa, uipath

I run such code in UIPath with VB

```
Dim doc As HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim num As Integer
doc = New HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml("<document><page><table><tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr></table></page><page><table><tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr></table></page></document>")
num = 1
For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
    i=0
    Try
        For Each row  As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[" & num.ToString & "]/tr[td]")
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Catch
        ss="//table[" & num.ToString & "]/tr[td]"
        docc = doc
        Exit For
    End Try
    num = num + 1
Next
```

I always get out by catch segment and get error with the 2nd table.
Do not know why?

When I investigate to the table, there are 2 tables. But refer to the 2nd in watch, I get null.

[image]

Comment: This is not xml so you should remove the tag.  It is html.  The for loop that enumerates rows should be selecting nodes from node not doc.

Comment: @jdweng Nothing's stopping you from editing to clean up the tags (unless the edit queue is full I guess?)

Comment: What's your expected output ? The values of the 2 tables ? You'll probably need the `.`(context) in your for XPath expression. `list = new List<string>(); foreach (element htmlNode in node) { list.Add(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode(".//td").InnerText.Trim());}`